# Looking for instruction that flips/reverses bytes in a word

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions, mars-simulator

I need to flip/reverse the bytes in a 4-byte word, for the purpose of displaying it on LED display.

Apparently there is one simple instruction to accomplish this, but I was unable to find it anywhere.

Comment: If you mean that it changes its endianness, then it's usually called `swap` or `bswap`.

Answer (score 0):

nor?

```
nor $d,$s,$t    $d = ~ ($s | $t)
```

**Edit:**

Can't seem to find a 32-bit byteswap instruction, but can you byteswap the halfwords and then swap the halfwords?

```
li   $t0,0xABCD    ;ABCD
wbsh $t0,$t0       ;BADC
rotr $v0,$v0,16    ;DCBA
```

Comment: Flips the bits, not reverses so much.

Comment: yeah.  With the LED simulator each LED is two bits, allowing for three colors and black (four states, obviously).  In a 32 bit alignment (r = red, g = green, o = orange, b - black) such as RRRR0000GGGGBBBB, I need it to become BBBBGGGG0000RRRR